# How do I make a div’s scrollbar always visible?

Tags: css, browser, scrollbar

How do I make my `div`’s scrollbar always visible?

```
.el {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
```

`overflow: scroll` is not working. It seems my browser’s native behavior does not allow that. (I’m on macOS.)

Is there some workaround?

P.S. The scroll bar is visible on hover, but I need it to always be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
html {
  height: 101%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a browser issue, the browser have there own style for these elements.

If scrollbar go to hidden, it's for the user comfort, you can't change this...

So you can try to make div scrollable with custom scrollbar plugin in jQuery for example :

https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar

This plugin create fake scrollbars in javascript and permit to user to scroll into element. So browser don't apply his own rules for these scrollbar because they aren't.